# What does ‘shoe–leather journalism’ mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

I found the word ‘Shoe-leather journalism’ in the following lead copy of the New York Times article (July 28) titled ‘In baring facts of train crash, bogs erode China censorship.’

> “China’s Twitter-like microblogs posted an astounding 26 million messages on the crash, a potent amalgam of contempt, suspicion and shoe-leather journalism.”

Merriam-Webster com.dictionary gives the definition of ‘shoe-leather’ as ‘involving or using basic, direct, or old-fashioned methods', and shows shoe–leather journalism as an example without any explanation.

Does ‘Shoe-leather journalism’ mean old-fashioned journalism or stereotype reporting style? Does it have something to do with a country’s governing system? What is the origin of ‘Shoe-leather journalism’?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The phrase is "shoe leather reporting".

I believe the meaning here is that genuine reporters will be out on the street walking, investigating, talking first-hand i.e. *wearing out the leather of their shoes* for a good quote or story. This is as opposed to [new media where people pick up online research or data and pass it off as journalism](http://bkstrategic.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/new-media-not-shoe-leather-reporting/).

My assumption turned out right, I've [updated to include a reference](http://www.danieldrezner.com/archives/001516.html)

> Part of the problem is that journalism terminology glorifies
>   "shoe-leather reporting," whereby you pound the pavement so often you
>   wear out the soles of your shoes.

Answer (score 4):

It more likely means basic or direct here, as the microbloggers described are not likely to be genuine news reporters of the old school, but simple *de facto* reporters who simply told what they saw. The "shoe leather" part refers to putting feet on pavement and going to get the story first-hand.

Comment: @Robust-san. So ‘shoe-leather journalism’ has positive nuance as a report based on first-hand information, not stereotype report under the government control as I first imagined being mislead by the word, ‘old fashioned methods’ in the definition of Merriam-Webster com?

Comment: @Yoichi Oishi: Oishi-san, it definitely has positive connotations in most cases. It could be used negatively, for example if someone were to extol the virtues of modern electronic information gathering over older methods — in which case it could be contrasted as slow and plodding — but it overwhelmingly is used in a positive way to convey doing something methodically, patiently, and (above all) in person.